# rsync changes directory name

Tags: command-line, nautilus, backup, sync, rsync

I just discovered rsync to sync my important files to an external storage. I used this command:

```
rsync -zavh /path/to/mylocaldirectory/ root:10.10.10.10/path/to/myexternalstorage
```

So far everything works. But what I accidentally discovered, when I use nautilus to look inside my synced directory, the directories inside have different names. One is called WMCLYO~K and the other WMSH8C~Z. Have no clue what this might mean. Interestingly, when I look into the synced directory via a terminal the original directory names show up.

Comment: Looks like these old FAT file names. Which files system is the target ?

Comment: ntfs, checked it with lsblk -f